# Create multiple arrays within a loop in vba?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to generate random values and storing them in array and would like to create multiple arrays within the loop. I have the inputs as follows in sheet1:

[image]

Following is the code I have but would like to avoid creating duplicate arrays - adj_a, adj_b, adj_c and instead loop them using a variable k = 1 To 3 and using something like adj(k)(i, j) and use offset to pick means and sd respectively. However, I get an error when I try to do that. Is this even possible? If not what's the best way to achieve this? In fact, I need to create 20 of these arrays and using an example of 3 here.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim rcount, ccount As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rcount = ws.Range("C3")
Set ccount = ws.Range("C4") '

'creates two dimensional array with random returns

Dim randgen() As Double: ReDim randgen(1 To rcount, 1 To ccount)
Dim adj_a() As Double: ReDim adj_a(1 To rcount, 1 To ccount)
Dim adj_b() As Double: ReDim adj_b(1 To rcount, 1 To ccount)
Dim adj_c() As Double: ReDim adj_c(1 To rcount, 1 To ccount)

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

For i = 1 To rcount 'loops over rows.Range
    For j = 1 To ccount 'loops over columns
        With WorksheetFunction
            On Error Resume Next 'sometimes norm inverse function can generate errors
                randgen(i, j) = .Norm_Inv(Rnd(), 0, 1)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        adj_a(i, j) = Exp(ws.Range("C6") + ws.Range("C7") * randgen(i, j))
        adj_b(i, j) = Exp(ws.Range("D6") + ws.Range("D7") * randgen(i, j))
        adj_a(i, j) = Exp(ws.Range("E6") + ws.Range("E7") * randgen(i, j))
    Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: You could use a `Scripting.Dictionary`, or a jagged array.

Comment: Yes, you would get an error with `adj(k)(i, j)` .  Why not just `adj(i, j, k)` ?